# How can I use HTML tags inside of a WPF application?

Tags: .net, html, wpf

I have some application in which some part of it should render HTML tags like `br`, `strong` and `img` (local image files) and show them exactly like in a modern browser.

Can I create a dynamic HTML page and load it into a browser control or is there any faster way of doing that?

Comment: Pointless down vote, i'm asp.net developer that doesn't know a thing about WPF not just asking dumb random questions with no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a browser control (but consider you might need to lock this down to prevent images, script, ... being loaded and used).

Or, if it is a simple enough subset of HTML, transform into a XAML [flow document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx).

Comment: @eugeneK IIRC you can get arbitrarily fine grained in any pre-processing you do.